# About intersection points of some diagonals of a regular $n$-gon

Tags: euclidean-geometry, polygons

Are my expectations true?

**My expectation 1** : There exist some intersection points, which are not on the center of the regular $n$-gon, of three or more diagonals when you draw all diagonals of a regular $n$-gon if and only if $n\ge 12$ is an even number.

**My expectation 2** : There is no intersection points of seven or more diagonals when you draw all diagonals of a regular $n$-gon for any $n$.

**My expectation 3** : There exist some intersection points of six diagonals when you draw all diagonals of a regular $n$-gon if and only if $n$ is a multiple of $30$.

If these are famous, please let me know some information about them.

**Example** : Let $f_i(n)$ be the number of intersection points of $i$ diagonals when you draw all diagonals of a regular $n$-gon.
$$f_2(18)=1512,f_3(18)=216, f_4(18)=54, f_5(18)=54.$$
The sum of these points is $1837.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See Poonen and Rubenstein, The number of intersection points made by the diagonals of a regular polygon, available at http://math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/ngon.pdf

Comment: Could you perhaps extract the necessary results from the paper?

Comment: I could, but I bet you could, too. Let me encourage you to do so.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Thank you very much for nice information.